# Why TIME_WAIT state is needed by active close side, but not the passive close side?

Tags: tcp, time-wait

Why TIME_WAIT state is needed by active close side, but not the passive close side?
I think the network error will affect both side, why only the active close side need to wait?

I think the passive side can also receive bad packet after the connection is closed.

Comment: Network errors and bad packets don't have anything to do with it, and it isn't about 'active' and 'passive' ends either. It is about *duplicated* packets, and about which side sent the first FIN.

Comment: @EJP Yes, duplicated packets can be received by the active end and the passive end, so, why only the active end (i.e., the one who first send FIN) have to wait for TIME_WAIT? why another end may 
 also receive duplicated packet but don't have to wait?

Comment: Because the end that first sent the FIN can't send any more packets, by definition.